# <video> doesn't work in Joomla 2.5 template index.php

Tags: php, html, templates, video, joomla

I have done a page in html and when I converted it to joomla 2.5 template I've got an issue.

- is not working in joomla template index.php file.

here is code

```
<video controls autoplay muted id="bgvid">
<source src="landing_video.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
```

and css

```
#bgvid {
position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;
}

video {
display: block;
}
```

This is code which makes video as a background, and it doesn't work in index.php joomla template.

Comment: check path of source video, is that correct?

Comment: Oh..... right!!!!! I spent so much time thinking about that... and I missed the easiest issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed thanks to Rahul,

I didn't check the path to video and that's why it didn't work.